# Failed to deploy an application into device like iPad-Linker command failed with Exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, sup

I am a beginner in native application.I am developing applications using Objective C as front end , SUP as middleware and SAP as backend.I have a valid provisioning certificate with a valid bundle identifier.I tried deploying one of my simple applications into the device(iPAD) which is not having any connection to the backend,and only having some basic navigations from one screen to another.And it has been successfully deployed.

But my problem is when I am deploying my application which is having connection to the middleware and using SUP libraries,it is showing build failed 'Linker command failed with Exit code 1'.I think it is because of the use of Libraries from SUP. **My application is running successfully with simulator**.Now what can I do for solving this?Please help me to solve this issue. **My Xcode version is 4.3 ,simulator is 5.1 and device version is 5.1.1(iPad2).**

A part of the error log is given bellow:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDataType", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_Installations.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomers.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImages.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceInstalledBase_Address.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceInstalledBase_Components.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDatabaseMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractStructure", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogKey in FieldServiceChangeLogKey.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPK in FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPK.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyPackageName in FieldServiceKeyPackageName.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPK in FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPK.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPKeyGenerator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceKeyGenerator.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyGenerator in FieldServiceKeyGenerator.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDefaultCallbackHandler", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_CallbackHandler in CallbackHandler.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPClassMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogKeyMetaData in FieldServiceChangeLogKeyMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPKMetaData in FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPKMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyPackageNameMetaData in FieldServiceKeyPackageNameMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPKMetaData in FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPKMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServicePersonalizationParametersMetaData in FieldServicePersonalizationParametersMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKeyMetaData in FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKeyMetaData.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPKeyGenerator", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyGenerator in FieldServiceKeyGenerator.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPClassDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogKey.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPK.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceKeyPackageName.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPK.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServicePersonalizationParameters.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKey.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPAbstractLogger", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceLoggerImpl in FieldServiceLoggerImpl.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPSISSubscriptionKey", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKey in FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKey.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPAbstractDBRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDatabaseManagerFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPLocalEntityDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceLocalKeyGenerator.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceOfflineAuthentication.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceOperationReplay.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPAbstractPersonalizationParameters", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServicePersonalizationParameters in FieldServicePersonalizationParameters.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_SUPAbstractDBRBS._messageListenerMap", referenced from:
      -[FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB defineMessageListenerForEntity:withClass:] in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPAbstractLocalEntity", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceOfflineAuthentication in FieldServiceOfflineAuthentication.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPLoginCredentials", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ConnectionController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAChartView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AnalysisViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DataGridViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPParameterMetaData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPStringUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPDatabaseMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AnalysisViewController in AnalysisViewController.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_DataGridViewController in DataGridViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPEntityMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData in FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomersMetaData in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData in FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_RetrieveMetaData in FieldServiceImage_RetrieveMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPLocalKeyGenerator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceLocalKeyGenerator.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceLocalKeyGenerator in FieldServiceLocalKeyGenerator.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPStringList", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_Installations.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomers.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_Capture.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_Retrieve.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImages.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_SUPAbstractDBRBS._concreteSubclass", referenced from:
      -[FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB initWithName:] in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPAbstractEntityRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogImpl in FieldServiceChangeLogImpl.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_Installations in FieldServiceCustomer_Installations.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomers in FieldServiceCustomers.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_Capture in FieldServiceImage_Capture.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_Retrieve in FieldServiceImage_Retrieve.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPSISSubscription", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceSISSubscription in FieldServiceSISSubscription.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPClassMap", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBOLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in CallbackHandler.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAttributeMap", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogKeyMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPBase64Encoding", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPOperationMetaData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_SUPAbstractDBRBS._queueConnection", referenced from:
      -[FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB queueConnection] in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPObjectList", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogImpl.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_Installations.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomers.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_Capture.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_Retrieve.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ConnectionController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAttributeMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogKeyMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPOperationMap", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractROEntity", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceOperationReplay in FieldServiceOperationReplay.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractPersonalizationParameters", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServicePersonalizationParameters in FieldServicePersonalizationParameters.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPAbstractStructure", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogKey in FieldServiceChangeLogKey.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPK in FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPK.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyPackageName in FieldServiceKeyPackageName.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPK in FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPK.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPIndexMetaData", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImagesMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceInstalledBase_AddressMetaData.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceInstalledBase_ComponentsMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPEntityMessageListener", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPSISSubscriptionKey", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKey in FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKey.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MAViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AnalysisViewController in AnalysisViewController.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_DataGridViewController in DataGridViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractLogger", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceLoggerImpl in FieldServiceLoggerImpl.o
  "_SUPDatabaseManager_UltraLite", referenced from:
      -[FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB initWithName:] in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPEntityMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineerMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData in FieldServiceChangeLogImplMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData in FieldServiceCustomer_InstallationsMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBasesMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomersMetaData in FieldServiceCustomersMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData in FieldServiceImage_CaptureMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_RetrieveMetaData in FieldServiceImage_RetrieveMetaData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPPersistenceException", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractDBRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_SUPAbstractPersonalizationParameters.clientPersonalizationTableName", referenced from:
      -[FieldServicePersonalizationParameters init] in FieldServicePersonalizationParameters.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPJsonObject", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractEntityRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogImpl in FieldServiceChangeLogImpl.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_Installations in FieldServiceCustomer_Installations.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceCustomers in FieldServiceCustomers.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_Capture in FieldServiceImage_Capture.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceImage_Retrieve in FieldServiceImage_Retrieve.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPSISSubscription", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceSISSubscription in FieldServiceSISSubscription.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPClassMetaDataRBS", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceChangeLogKeyMetaData in FieldServiceChangeLogKeyMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPKMetaData in FieldServiceKeyGeneratorPKMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceKeyPackageNameMetaData in FieldServiceKeyPackageNameMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPKMetaData in FieldServiceLocalKeyGeneratorPKMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServicePersonalizationParametersMetaData in FieldServicePersonalizationParametersMetaData.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKeyMetaData in FieldServiceSISSubscriptionKeyMetaData.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPAbstractROEntity", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceOperationReplay in FieldServiceOperationReplay.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPDefaultCallbackHandler", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CallbackHandler in CallbackHandler.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPEntityDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceAssign_ServiceEngineer.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceChangeLogImpl.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_Installations.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomer_InstalledBases.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCustomers.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_Capture.o
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceImage_Retrieve.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPQueueConnectionImpl", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPAbstractLocalEntity", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_FieldServiceOfflineAuthentication in FieldServiceOfflineAuthentication.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAKitTheme_WelterWeight", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AnalysisViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in DataGridViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPQuery", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUPLocalKeyGenerator", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_FieldServiceLocalKeyGenerator in FieldServiceLocalKeyGenerator.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPEntityMap", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DBMetaData.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SUPDatabaseDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FieldServiceCom_igate_Reshma_fieldservice_ALL_v6DB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Show the exact error you have. Linker command failed with Exit code 1 is not enough.

Comment: Still missing the detailed error, after your edit :)

Comment: @PsychoWood,Robert Vojta :Now I have included the detailed error.Plese check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not linking correctly the SUP libraries in your project.

**Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries**

```
libAfariaSLL.a
libclientrt.a
libDatavault.a
libMO.a
libsupcore.a
libSUPObj.a
libsupUltralite.a
```

(these are the libraries for SUP 2.1.3, different version could mean different libraries).

Also check if the libraries are in your search path (I have the libraries in the root of my .xcworkspace)

**Project -> Target -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Library Search Paths**

```
"$(SRCROOT)/../libraries/RBS/Libraries/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)"
```

Comment: PsychoWood:We have added these above mentioned 7 files by using 'Link binary with Libraries'.And in my LibrarySearch paths,I have ticked the option
 "$(SRCROOT)/--/--/extraz/simpleRBS/Libraries/Debug-iPhoneSimulator"

In my buildsettings 'Architectectures' option is having the entry 
'Standard(armv&)-$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)'
and 'valid Architecures' is having the entry 'armv6 armv7'.

Comment: :When I build my application on device it is giving me warnings like:
** ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/chairman/Desktop/Final_Field/Final_Field/libAfariaSLL.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7)** for every added .a files

Comment: You need to use the variables $(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) or create different targets for the simulator and the device. Your configuration will use "Debug-iPhoneSimulator" architecture libs, which are for x86 and won't work on a arm device, you need the ones in "Debug-iphoneos".

Comment: :I changed my library search path as u said,and I used .a files from 'Debug-iPhoneos'.But it showed the same results.Something may be wrong with my settings.Since I am not much familiar with the application it seems difficult for me to sort out.

Comment: Did you try to deploy the SUP101 example (that should work out-of-the-box), and then check the differences with your settings?

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved for me.What I did is I created a new project with .a files from Debug-iPhoneOS and did the code signing properly.And also changed the bundle identifier name according to the provisional certificate details.It worked for me.